# Loading large pickle files into variable accesses hard disks instead of loading into RAM

Tags: python, ipython, pickle, bigdata

I have a large pickle file (about 5GB) that contains data that I need to regularly access to run a simulation. This file contains 3x1.6 Million lines of float values.

```
with open('Largepicklefile.pkl') as f:  # Python 3: open(..., 'wb')
    datR=pickle.load(f)
```

I use this variable `datR` as part of the simulation. I have 16GB RAM that is hardly used when I load this pickle file but it seems to access the hard drive to read the file regularly (noted from file timestamps and major hard disk activity). I am hoping to improve my simulation speed by less hard disk access. How do I directly load large pickle file into memory (or large chunks into memory) at a time so that hard disk is minimally accessed?

Comment: I really really doubt, pickle is not reading the whole file at once and put everything into the memory. Consider reading the offical docs and re-think about your *reason-to-think-otherwise*. (the only disk-load behaviour i can think of has nothing to do with python: it's OS trashing when you got not enough memory)

Comment: To be more clear: *trashing* is usually the behaviour after everything is too late. Before that happens, the OS can perfectly fine use swapping to virtually support more memory (at the cost of disk-reads).

Comment: I am on OS X Sierra if it can make any difference. So, you say it tried to load into memory but because of some reason (lack of available RAM?) it is loaded in swap?

Comment: That's a possibility (that swap is somehow used; but if the internel object-size easily fits into memory; using swap after should stop). Read the docs on pickle's internals. A 5GB-file might easily need way more memory while unpickling.